# Fast way to create incidence matrix from list of label python?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, cluster-analysis, vectorization

I have an array `y, len(y) = M` that contains values from `0 -> N`. For example, with `N = 3`:

```
y = [0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2]
```

Incidence matrix `A` is defined as followed:

- Size `MxM`
- `A(i,j) = 1 if y(i) == y(j)`
- `A(i,j) = 0 if y(i) != y(j)`

A simple algorithm would be:

```
def incidence(y):
    M = len(y)
    A = np.zeros((M,M))
    for i in range(M):
        for j in range(M):
            if y[i]==y[j]:
                A[i,j] = 1
    return A
```

But this is very slow. Is there any way to do this faster? Using list comprehension or vectorization, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of numpy broadcasting to gain some efficiency here over our python by simply asking if `y` equals its transpose:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2])

def mat_me(y):
    return (y == y.reshape(-1, 1)).astype(int)

mat_me(y)
```

which produces:

```
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

for comparison:

```
y = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=3000)

def mat_me_py(y):
    return (y == y.reshape([-1, 1])).astype(int)

%timeit mat_me_py(y)  
# 28.6 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

vs.

```
y = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=3000)
y = list(y)

def mat_me_py(y):
    return [[int(a == b) for a in y] for b in y]

%timeit mat_me_py(y)
# 4.16 s ± 213 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The difference will become very pronounced on larger lists.